# Связи в базе данных (mysql)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Пытаюсь спроектировать базу данных (mysql) для будущего чата - мессенджера.
Вот получившаяся на данный момент модель:
[image: Модель базы]

Я новичок в базах данных, и у меня появляется 2 вопроса:

1. Я связываю диалог и его пользователей через dialogusers. Достаточно ли добавить в dialogusers связь с dialogId, или должна быть обратная связь? Правильный ли это ход вообще создавать связь таким образом, или лучше сделать это напрямую? Когда связь onetoone, надо ли делать 2 переменные в сущности для двусторонней связи?
2. Связь "Пользователь - созданные сообщения" - у меня выходит manytoone, а должно быть onetomany. Workbench никак не хочет инвертировать эту связь, не пойму почему!

UPD:

***Необходимые связи:***

У каждого чата (dialog) есть 1 список пользователей (dialogusers). Связь OneToOne.

У чата (dialog) может быть создатель (user). Связь OneToOne.

Список пользователей (dialogusers) содержит, соответственно, самих пользователей(user), подключенных к диалогу. Он может быть пустым. Связь OneToMany

Каждый пользователь (user) имеет 1 профиль (userprofile). Связь OneToOne.

Каждое сообщение (message) имеет одного отправителя (user). Связь OneToOne.

Каждое сообщение (message) имеет один чат (dialog), уда оно, собственно, отправлено. Связь OneToOne.

Вышеназванные связи реализовать, вроде как, удалось.

***Со следующими связями есть проблемы в реализации и вообще в их необходимости:***

У пользователя (user) могут быть отправленные сообщения (message). Связь OneToMany. При реализации выходит обратная связь - ManyToOne.

У списка пользователей (dialogUsers) стоит ссылка на чат этого списка (dialog). Я не знаю, нужна ли мне эта связь впирнципе и как я ее буду использовать.

Comment: Опубликуйте анализ предметной области, по результатам которого построена эта диаграмма.

Comment: *Workbench никак не хочет инвертировать эту связь, не пойму почему!* На стороне уникального индекса может быть только "один".

Comment: _Опубликуйте анализ предметной области, по результатам которого построена эта диаграмма_ - знать бы еще, о чем вы говорите...

Comment: _На стороне уникального индекса может быть только "один"_ - мне нужно что бы от пользователя можно было найти все сообщения, которые он отправлял. Т.е. много сообщений от одного пользователя. А выходит наоборот: много пользователей привязываю к одному сообщению.

Comment: Ну потому что анализ проведён неправильно, не сообщение есть атрибут пользователя, а наоборот.

Comment: Но такая связь у меня есть. Т.е. в сообщении есть атрибут "отправитель", я хотел еще в пользователя добавить "отправленные сообщения". Кстати говоря, я сейчас думаю "зачем оно мне вообще надо", и, все-таки, мне непонятно: почему нельзя создать такую связь?

Comment: Потому что отправленное сообщение не является атрибутом отправителя.

Comment: PS. Всё-таки будет хорошо, если Вы серьёзно изучите тему проектирования баз данных. Правильно построенная схема убережёт от многих проблем в будущем. А по чужим советам Вы её построите мало того что приблизительно (запросто может оказаться, что построенная из общих соображений схема не соответствует Вашей конкретной предметной области), так ещё Вы её построите и без понимания что, где как и, главное, почему именно так. А чем больше схема, тем сложнее её корректировать в правильном направлении.

Comment: Обновил основной вопрос. Не знаю, это ли Вы подразумеваете под "анализом предметной области"...

Comment: Анализ предметной области имеет итогом выделенные сущности, атрибуты, связи (всё, что является основой для построения ER-диаграммы) и процессы.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, буду искать ответ на вопрос в теме проектирования баз данных.